# Laravel: How to populate existing data with a foreignkey?

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, one-to-one

I build a two models which represent two tables in my mysql database.
In one table I got the zip codes of some car dealers and in the second one I got the coordinates
of zip codes.
Unfortunatly, I don't get
the related data.
I used the zip_code aus the foreign_key.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('plzs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->text("Ort");
        $table->decimal('Latitude', 10, 8);
        $table->decimal('Longitude', 11, 8);
    });
}
```

and

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('autodealers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->bigInteger('plz_id')->unsigned();
        $table->text("Händler");

        $table->foreign('plz_id')->references('id')->on('plzs')->onDelete('cascade');          
    });
}
```

then I migrate the table and the table is created in my db.
After that I import via csv files data to the tables in mySQL. Everything works fine.

Here I define the one-to-one relationship.
plz.php:

```
public function dealer()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Autodealer', 'plz_id');
}
```

Autodealer.php:

```
public function coor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\plz');
}
```

Via web.php I'm defining the route:

```
Route::get('/auto', 'AutohaendlerController@index');
```

From this Route I'm calling the index method:

```
public function index()
{
    $dealer = \App\Autodealer::all();
    return view('plz', array('ausgabe'=>$dealer));
}
```

It works perfectly fine when my view looks like:

```
<body>

    <ul>
        @foreach ($ausgabe as $dealer)
            <li>{{$dealer}}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
```

But when I use `<li>{{$dealer->coor}}</li>` instead, no data is displayed.
The coor() funktion should call the belongTo method.
In tinker my data seems to be also unrelated.

What I am missing?

When I use tinker and save a plz object and a Autodealer object with the same id and plz_id, it works.
It seems to be a problem, when I'm importing my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I used Tinker I noticed, that I could not save an object without `updated_at`, `created_at`.
Tinker throws this SQL-Error:

Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `plzs` (`id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (33611, 2020-07-02 11:18:12, 2020-07-02 11:18:12))'

So I added timestamps to my Tables:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('plzs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->text("Ort");
        $table->decimal('Latitude', 10, 8);
        $table->decimal('Longitude', 11, 8);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('autodealers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        //connect to the plzs table via reference to plz table
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('plz_id');
        $table->text("Händler");

        //index for any foreign key
        $table->index('plz_id');  
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

In mySQL the `updated_at`, `created_at` colums of each table must have set additionally CURRENT-TIME standard, in order fill the `updated_at` and `created_at` colums during the import of csv-data.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing keys in the coor() relationship. You're not using id in the autodealers table as the foreign key, so you need to set that in the relationship.

```
public function coor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\plz', 'id', 'plz_id');
}
```

Comment: When I add the key 'plz_id' I get an error, because 'App\plz' doesn't have the 'plz_id'-column.  When I add 'id', the problem is not solved. I think 'id' is used on default as reference.

Comment: You are correct that `id` is the default column that Laravel looks for in relationships. `plz_id` is the key on the `autodealers` table that you need to use to connect the two tables. You can try `$this->belongsTo('App\plz', 'plz_id');`, but I'm pretty sure the original answer is correct. If that doesn't work, there might be something else that's off. Make sure when you output in the view that you use a property from the relationship instead of the relationship itself. ie: `<li>{{$dealer->coor->Latitude}}</li>`